# VBA: How to delete the next three rows based on criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that only deletes the row containing the letters **PGM:AGEDP**  but I don't know how to delete the next **three rows** following the first delete. The three rows after **PGM:AGEDP** row are junk they contain some letters, numbers and symbols which come in variety everytime but letters **PGM:AGEDP** will always stay the same . Just for simplicity, if the first row contains the letters then it should be deleted with the bottom three more rows.These four rows come very offend in the whole worksheet more than 30Xs

```
Sub RemovingPGM()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Activate

  Dim n As Long
    Dim nlast As Long
    Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    nlast = rw.Count
    For n = nlast To 1 Step -1
        If (rw.Cells(n, 1).Value = "PGM:AGEDP") Then
            rw.Rows(n).Delete
        End If
    Next n
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Any question regarding further explanation please feel free to ask.

Comment: rw.Rows(n).Resize(4).Delete

Comment: You could do: rw.Rows(n).Delete,rw.Rows(n-1).Delete, rw.Rows(n-2).Delete, rw.Rows(n-4).Delete

Comment: @user3598756 Lol Thank you, that worked just fine.

Comment: @VBAPete This works too

Comment: No worries @MTBthePRO

Comment: @user3598756 - How have I not come across `Resize()` before?! Thanks for that.

Comment: @BruceWayne, you most probably simply don't remember it!

Comment: @MTBthePRO, you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Sub Second_DeletingPGM()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nlast As Long
    Dim rw As Range

    Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows

    nlast = rw.Count
    For n = nlast To 1 Step -1
        If (rw.Cells(n, 1).Value = "PGM:AGEDP") Then
            rw.Rows(n).Resize(4).Delete
        End If

    Next n
End Sub
```